# Wannacrypt - MS Outlook email

Tags: malware

I use MS Outlook for email and have an exchange account such that the email is stored on my laptop as well as in the cloud.
Is it safe to rely on the cloud version of the mail as a backup in the event that my laptop is infected with Wannacrypt and the local OST file becomes encrypted?

Comment: do you consider the cloud safe for backup at all? if so this question is moot, if not . get a proper backup facility and this question is moot.

Comment: Why do you care about the OST file? The OST files are simply used for caching and offline browsing of emails and shouldn't be considered backups. The email is stored on your exchange server so it shouldn't matter if your laptop gets hosed, your email should still exist on your Exchange server (which _should_ be getting backed up regularly)